# Php split a string escaping quotas

Tags: php, regex, split

I need to manage escaping in a comma split.
This is a string example:

```
var1,t3st,ax_1,c5\,3,last
```

I need this split:

```
var1
t3st
ax_1
c5\,3
last
```

Please mind this: "c5\,3" is not splitted.

I tried with this:

```
$expl=preg_split('#[^\\],#', $text);
```

But i loose the last char of each split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex

```
$str = 'var1,t3st,ax_1,c5\,3,last';
$expl=preg_split('#(?<!\\\),#', $str);

print_r($expl);  // output Array ( [0] => var1 [1] => t3st [2] => ax_1 [3] => c5\,3 [4] => last )
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/pWSu3S

Comment: I would like to correct your code like this `$expl = preg_split('#(?<!\\\),#', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`. To avoid empty elements in an array

Answer (score 1):

Try with a lookbehind:

```
preg_split('#(?<!\\),#', $text);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow escape the last slash in you answer: '#(?<!\\\\),#'

Answer (score 0):

Do a 3 phase approach

First replace \, with someting "unique" like \\

Do your split by ","

Replace \\ with \,

That not as nice as regex but it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

is this ok ?

```
<?php

$text = "var1,t3st,ax_1,c5\,3,last";
$text = str_replace("\,", "#", $text);
$xpode = explode(",", $text);
$new_text = str_replace("#", "\,", $xpode);
print_r($new_text);

?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => var1 [1] => t3st [2] => ax_1 [3] => c5\,3 [4] => last )
```